# Cap/Floor sequence of numbers with minimum deviation from original sequence

Tags: python, numpy, minimization

I have a `list` `a` of `floats` and trying to apply cap `maxV` and floor `minV` to each element such that the sum of the elements in the `list` remains constant `sumV`. This should be done in a fashion so as to minimize sum(|a_new/a_orig - 1|), where || is abs function.

Could someone help refine the following approach:

```
>>> a, maxV, minV, sumV = [1.,2.,3.,4.,5.], 4.5, 2.1, 14
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.copy(a)*sumV/np.sum(a)
>>> flr = a < minV
>>> cp = a > maxV
>>> while not (sum(flr) == 0 & sum(cp) == 0):
>>>    a[flr] = minV
>>>    a[cp] = maxV
>>>    sumChanged = np.sum(a[flr | cp])
>>>    sumUnchanged = np.sum(a[(~flr) & (~cp)])
>>>    a[(~flr) & (~cp)] *= (sumV - sumChanged)/sumUnchanged
>>>    flr = a < minV
>>>    cp = a > maxV
>>> a
>>> array([ 2.1,  2.1,  2.27142857,  3.02857143,  4.5])
>>>
```

Comment: It will be easier for folks to offer help if you include the result you hope to get and what you're getting instead.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thanks for your response. I am not sure if giving sample result (different decimal accuracy) will help come up with the solution better. The objective is to minimize sum(abs(a_new/a_orig - 1)) subject to 3 constraints.

Comment: Seems like perhaps you have a math problem, not a programming problem.